# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [2] Access denied

Tags: api, soap

I am trying to login via soap from an external server

```
$api_url_v2 = "http://www.example.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1";
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$cli = new SoapClient($api_url_v2);
$session_id = $cli->login($username, $password);
```

The error message I get is Fatal error:

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [2] Access denied

However if I look in the `api_user` table in magento db, then the lognum column increments by 1 when I have the correct username / password combo... so it seems like the system knows the details are correct, but is giving me access denied.

The users role I have ticked all options for and assigned the role to the user

I can't seem to see many examples of this issue anywhere.

Has anyone come accross this issue, or can you provide any tips to solve?

Answer (score 3):

Please try this connection code:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
```

I took it from the API Guidlines here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html#Introduction-SOAPAPIVersionv2

I have also used this method on my stores for product retrieval and editting, however, are you on version 1.6.2? I know there is a role setting bug that doesnt allow you to set all roles.

**Suggestions:**
Provide version number, edition & url if possible.

---

**REVISION:**

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://www.comain.co.uk/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1');
$session = $client->login('username', 'apikey');

$result = $client->catalogInventoryStockItemList($session, array('27847')); // Products ID
print_r($result);
```

The above code has just been tested on my server which seems to be succesfull with this result:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 27847 [sku] => VKC450O [qty] => 0.0000 [is_in_stock] => 1 ) )
```

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Thats the same code as i am already using right? Magento version 1.7.0.2

Comment: Yes, without using lots of variables, and keeping it simpler, could you provide url link? Also, are you in WS-I COMPLIANCE mode or not?

Comment: WS-I COMPLIANCE - No.. But this is an issue with logging in, not anything to do with requests or XML formats

Comment: I have editted my answer

Comment: Thanks for your kind help adam... I cannot use the api, as it appears to be not even logging in.. As mentioned, the api_user database seems to be incrementing one of the columns with correct details which leads me to assument the details are correct...So not sure where it is going wrong really... I will maybe have to try with a default install, or turn off modules and see if there is a conflict somewhere

Comment: Is this a result of a custom module guide?

Comment: ok, i made some more progress... I have found out the actual error message for why access is denied.. Now i just need to fix that Uncaught SoapFault exception: [2] Parent Role id 'G1' does not exist

Comment: Hi eleven have a look at your role users that may help you the id im guessing will be the entity number associated with the role user

Comment: ok i fixed it... In this table api_role.. There was an entry for a user (role_type = U). For each one of these users, there needs to be a role_id (role_type = G) that has an id of the users parent_id.. So i deleted the user with no referenced parent and it fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$client = new SoapClient(
    'http://127.0.0.1/magento/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'
);

$session = $client->login('imran', '654321imran');

$result = $client->catalogProductList($session,'sku');

print_r($result->product_id);

$client->endSession($session);
```

Comment: It would be much better if you provide some explanation as well with the code.

Answer (score 0):

One idea: load the WSDL-config with cUrl like this example and try it again:

```
// GET SOAP-WSDL AS TEMP-FILE
// ==========================

    $objCURL = curl_init([API-URL]); // Set API-URL
    curl_setopt($objCURL,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $strWSDLFile = curl_exec($objCURL);
    curl_close($objCURL);

    file_put_contents('wsdl_temp.xml',$strWSDLFile);

// INIT SOAP-SESSION
// =================

    try {
        $soap = new SoapClient('wsdl_temp.xml');
        $soapSession = $soap->login([API-User], [API-Key]);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e);
    }
```

This solves all MY problems with the API. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to 

1. create a new SOAP/XML-RPX Roles, say "Test" 

2. in Role Resources just select "All" for Resource Access (just for testing) 

3. Edit the user and assign the Role to "Test"

Answer (score 0):

[image: SoapFault: Forbidden in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\soap\class_01.php on line 128]

In fact, if I use Soap in http://localhost/.... it works, the connection is successful, but if I use same methods with in external IP and a port (like http://82.82.10.10:8080/...) returns this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Forbidden in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\soap\class_01.php on line 128

SoapFault: Forbidden in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\soap\class_01.php on line 128

The firewall is disabled, the ports are open. I do not know what to look for.